# RecyclerView dosn't show any lists

Tags: android, xml

I am new to android development, I am trying to build a news app, I think somthing is wrong with my RecyclerView, it supposed to show me a list of images, but when I load the app the screen is empty

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.newsapp_3.viewmodels.NewsViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.newsapp_3.FragmentOverview">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_main"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:padding="6dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:listData="@{viewModel.newsList}"
            tools:listitem="@layout/headline_list_item" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: please add the java/kotlin code here... Recycler view by default will not display any items, you need to load item from the recycler view adapter

Comment: Please show your java code.

Comment: I have changed the LinearLayout to ConstraintLayout, and it works now. but whats interesting is why recyclerviews don't work with LinearLaouts?

Comment: @SamiKassoum They work perfectly with LinearLayout. You've used 0dp for your RecyclerView height & width and while for ConstraintLayout this means stretch-according-to-constraints, for LinearLayout it simply means zero size.

Comment: Thanks gioravered, now I have learned something important. Thank you all for your caring answers!